# Function Hooking with C++

Tags: hook

If I understand correctly, with this, functions within a program can be tracked down and modified.

Let's just say I had a .exe in c++ that just does the following in a loop:

```
void func()
{
    printf("A");
}
```

What tools would I need to intercept the function within that .exe and instead change the function to do something like printf("B") instead?

Comment: "This" does not even compile ;)

Comment: Edited.  My bad, I rushed when I was writing it... :|
Been doing too much python lately

Comment: Take your time writing your questions and you get more useful answers. Most likely the function you show will be inlined by an optimizing compiler and not even exist any longer in an exe.  So, my guess is, you ask about how to make a c++ program extensible. Probably by means of a shared library programmed against a pre-defined header file or so?